# flutter - responsive height Form

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this simple form, with a textarea and buttons:

[image]

When I open the keyboard, I want to decrease the size of the textarea, like a responsive layout. If I close the keyboard, the textarea should fill the remaining screen space available.

[image]

*desired effect: open / active keyboard*

[image]

*desired effect: closed/no keyboard*

My intention is to make the components fill in the screen, regardless device resolution.

Can someone provide a valida example of it? I tried several implementations and I was not able to achive the desired effect.

*UPDATE:*

My current code for this screen:

```
new MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) {
    return new Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text('Add new Grocery List'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new IconButton(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.delete),
          tooltip: 'Clear Grocery List',
          onPressed: () {
            this._promptRemoveGroceryBatchList();
          },
        ),
      ]
    ),
    body: new Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: new Form(
      key: this._formGroceryBatchAdd,
      child: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          child: new Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              new TextFormField(
                maxLines: 10,
                autofocus: true,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Item List',
                  hintText: 'Enter a grocery list',
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0)
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter at least one grocery item';
                  }
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  this._formBatchGroceryData = value;
                },
              ),
              new Padding(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: new Text(
                  'One item per line. Use ":" to specifcy the amount.\n' +
                  'Example:\n' +
                  'Potatoes:12\n' +
                  'Tomatoes:6',
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black54),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        new Container(
          child: new ButtonBar(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            new RaisedButton(
              child: new Text('Add Items'),
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              elevation: 4.0,
              onPressed: () {
                // ACTION GOES HERE
              },
            ),
            new RaisedButton(
              child: new Text('Cancel'),
              onPressed: () {
                // ACTION GOES HERE
              },
            ),
          ] 
          ),
        ),
        ]
      )
      );
    )
    );
  }
)
```

Comment: could you share your code?

Comment: @diegoveloper Done. I updated my question with the current code that I use for this screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it can't be directly done using a `TextField` for the textarea because its size depends on the lines of text you have.

But you can simulate it by surrounding the `TextField` that allows unlimited lines with a Container.

This is a sample that could work for you:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 10.0, bottom: 20.0, right: 10.0),
                  child: new TextField(
                    maxLines: null,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```